# how to save user input in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview

I add “Employee” to the SQLite database. When adding an employee to the database, the user must fill in the fields that relate to the employee, for example, first name, last name, salary, etc. The employee has several attributes such as "skill" and "department" of these attributes the employee may have several, so when the user fills in all the fields with attributes he is invited to add another field, for example, the field "skill" to add another "skill", such a field " skill "you can add as much as you want and I implemented it with RecyclerView. But the problem is this: when the user wants to add another "skill" field, an empty EditText appears and the user fills this field with data, but I don’t know how to save this line, because when you click add skill an empty line is transferred to the adapter, then the user fills this line, but how to save this line to the list that contains the adapter I can not figure out

[please watch a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFX7t.gif)

This is Adapter class

```
public class AdapterAddSkill extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAddSkill.MyViewHolderAddEmployee> {
private ArrayList<String> skillsList;
private Context context;

public AdapterAddSkill(ArrayList<String> skillsList, Context context) {
    this.skillsList = skillsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolderAddEmployee onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_skill, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolderAddEmployee(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolderAddEmployee holder, final int position) {
    holder.closeCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            skillsList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return skillsList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}



public static class MyViewHolderAddEmployee extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageButton closeCard;
    private EditText skillEditText;

    public MyViewHolderAddEmployee(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        closeCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteSkillCard);
        skillEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillText);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the activity in which the user fills in the data about the employee and adds it to the database

```
public class AddEmploy extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText nameEditText, lastNameEditText, employeeIdEditText,
        salaryEditText, departmentEditText, skillEditText;
private ArrayList<String> skillsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> departmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
private AdapterAddSkill adapterAddSkill;
private RecyclerView skillRecyclerView;
private AdapterAddDepartment adapterAddDepartment;
private RecyclerView departmentRecyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employ);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.name);
    lastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    employeeIdEditText = findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
    salaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.salary);
    departmentEditText = findViewById(R.id.department);
    skillEditText = findViewById(R.id.skill);
    skillRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_skill);
    departmentRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_department);
    adapterAddSkill = new AdapterAddSkill(skillsList, this);
    adapterAddDepartment = new AdapterAddDepartment(departmentsList, this);
    skillRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    departmentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    skillRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAddSkill);
    departmentRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAddDepartment);

}

public void onClickBtn(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.addDepartmentText:
            departmentsList.add("");
            adapterAddDepartment.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case R.id.addSkillText:
            skillsList.add("");
            adapterAddSkill.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case R.id.saveEmployee_info:
            addEmployToDatabase();
            addDepartmentToDatabase();
            addSkillToDatabase();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void addEmployToDatabase() {
    String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
    String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
    String lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString();
    String salary = salaryEditText.getText().toString();
    MyQuery.addEmployee(new Employ(employeeId, name, lastName, salary));
}

private void addSkillToDatabase() {
    String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
    String skill = skillEditText.getText().toString();
    MyQuery.addSkill(new Skill(employeeId, skill));
    for (int i = 0; i < skillsList.size(); i++) {
        MyQuery.addSkill(new Skill(employeeIdEditText.getText().toString()
                , skillsList.get(i)));
    }
}

private void addDepartmentToDatabase() {
    String department = departmentEditText.getText().toString();
    String employeeId = employeeIdEditText.getText().toString();
    MyQuery.addDepartment(new Department(employeeId, department));
    for (int i = 0; i < departmentsList.size(); i++) {
        MyQuery.addDepartment(new Department(employeeIdEditText.getText().toString(),
                departmentsList.get(i)));
    }
}

private void showAllEmployees() {
    List<Employ> employs = MyQuery.getAllEmployees();
    for (int i = 0; i < employs.size(); i++) {
        Log.i(".......Employees", employs.get(i).toString());
    }
}

private void showAllSkills() {
    List<Skill> skills = MyQuery.getAllSkills();
    for (int i = 0; i < skills.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("......Skills", skills.get(i).toString());
    }
}

private void showAllDepartments() {
    List<Department> departments = MyQuery.getAllDepartments();
    for (int i = 0; i < departments.size(); i++) {
        Log.i(".........Departments", departments.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AdapterAddSkill extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAddSkill.MyViewHolderAddEmployee> {
private ArrayList<String> skillsList;

public AdapterAddSkill(ArrayList<String> skillsList) {
    this.skillsList = skillsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolderAddEmployee onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_skill, parent, false);
    MyViewHolderAddEmployee vh = new MyViewHolderAddEmployee(view, new MyCustomEditTextListener());
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolderAddEmployee holder, final int position) {
    holder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(position);
    holder.skillEditText.setText(skillsList.get(position));

    holder.closeCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            skillsList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return skillsList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}



public static class MyViewHolderAddEmployee extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private ImageButton closeCard;
   private EditText skillEditText;
   private MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;


    public MyViewHolderAddEmployee(@NonNull View itemView, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
        super(itemView);
        closeCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteSkillCard);
        skillEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillText);
        skillEditText.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);
        this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
    }


}

private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        skillsList.set(position, s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

}